# jQuery / Ajax properly sending "data-" value in an alert, but unable to append it into a specific div inside a php for

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I currently have an html button which right below has a div where I want to post certain data.

Both of those elements are inside a php for loop.

```
<?php for($i = 0 ; $i < 10; $i++){ ?>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <button data-dnipass="<?= $dni?>" class="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Ver líneas
                  </button>
              </div>
       </div>   
  <div id ="<?= $i?>" class="table userInfo" data-formpost="<?= $dni?>"></div> 
<? } ?>
```

`$dni` is a value I take from my databae and is unique for each iteration.

Then I have an ajax script doing the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".ver").click(function(event){
        var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass"); //this is properly asigning the data
        alert(pulsado); //this properly launches an alert with my desired value
        $(this).data("formpost").append(pulsado); //im trying to append my variable to my ".userinfo" div but im unable to do so, since I dont know how to identify so
    });
    })
```

How can I append the var pulsado to my div with the class ."userinfo"? The content of the var pulsado is a simple string, like "x1234" or "x4321"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
    $(".ver").click(function(event){
        var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass"); //this is properly asigning the data
        $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.userInfo').append(pulsado);
    });
```

The `closest` finds the `div` under which your `button` is wrapped. `next` then finds the immediate `div` with `userInfo` class.

Comment: Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of append() like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".ver").on('click',function(event)
   {
      var pulsado = $(this).data("dnipass");
      $(".userinfo").append(pulsado);
   });
});
```

Comment: Problem that way, is that it will append the data to each of my divs without taking into account that they should be unique, somehow identified to the button right above. In fact the id can be set to the "pulsado" value, but I dont know what to do next